# Game doesn't play on second frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm currently trying to work on a game, which is for a college assignment. I'm using flash and actionscript 3 to do so (I'm using an older version of flash, which is a 2015 version, back when it was still called Adobe Flash). When placing code within the first frame, player object movement works fine, however when I place it all in the second frame, this does not work. Why? The code is completely the same! And I think it would be more convenient if I had gameplay start from frame 2 (at the very least have the first level be held at this frame). At frame 1, I want to have my main menu. So, here is the code that I currently have at frame 1:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();


var optionsActive:Boolean = false;
var gamePaused:Boolean = false;

startGame();

function startGame():void
{
    if (optionsActive == false)
    {
        optionsUI.visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        optionsUI.visible = true;
    }
    menuTextOptions_active.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, activateMenuOptions);
    menuTextNewgame_active.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, activateStartNewGame);

}

function activateStartNewGame(event:Event)
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}

function activateMenuOptions(event:Event)
{
    optionsActive = true;
    optionsUI.visible = true;
    if (this.currentFrame == 1)
    {
        if (menuTextContinue_active.visible != false)
        {
            menuTextContinue_active.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuTextNewgame_active.visible != false)
        {
            menuTextNewgame_active.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuTextOptions_active.visible != false)
        {
            menuTextOptions_active.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuTextExitgame_active.visible != false)
        {
            menuTextExitgame_active.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuButton_continue.visible != false)
        {
            menuButton_continue.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuButton_newgame.visible != false)
        {
            menuButton_newgame.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuButton_options.visible != false)
        {
            menuButton_options.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuButton_exitgame.visible != false)
        {
            menuButton_exitgame.visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code that I currently have at frame 2:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

var keybaordLeft:int = 37;
var keyboardUp:int = 38;
var keyboardRight:int = 39;
var keyboardDown:int = 40;

var playerXSpeed:int = 4;
var playerYSpeed:int = 4;

var leftDown:Boolean = false;
var upDown:Boolean = false;
var rightDown:Boolean = false;
var downDown:Boolean = false;

optionsActive = false;
gamePaused = false;

startLevel();

function startLevel():void
{
    if (optionsActive == false)
    {
        optionsUI.visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        optionsUI.visible = true;
    }
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, activateMenuOptions);

    mc_playerShip.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePlayer);

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeysDown);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeysUp);
}

function checkKeysDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == 37)
    {
        leftDown=true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 38)
    {
        upDown=true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39)
    {
        rightDown=true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40)
    {
        downDown=true;
    }
}

function checkKeysUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == 37)
    {
        leftDown=false;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 38)
    {
        upDown=false;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39)
    {
        rightDown=false;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40)
    {
        downDown=false;
    }
}

function movePlayer(event:Event):void
{
    if (leftDown)
    {
        mc_playerShip.x -= playerXSpeed;
    }
    if (upDown)
    {
        mc_playerShip.y -= playerYSpeed;
    }
    if (rightDown)
    {
        mc_playerShip.x += playerXSpeed;
    }
    if (downDown)
    {
        mc_playerShip.y += playerYSpeed;
    }
}
```

And the character does not move at all. why is this and how could I fix it?

Comment: where is located your `mc_playerShip`? did you get any error throwing after execute? or any run time errors?

Comment: It is on-screen. I wouldn't be able to tell what's wrong if it's not on-screen. It is only present in the second frame, of course. And no, I didn't get any errors.

Comment: What if you add the enter frame event listener to the stage instead of the ship? I'm not sure that will fix it, but I don't see the point in adding it to the ship. I always add mine to the stage.

Comment: In my experience, adding code to frames always leads to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question but may still be helpful.

```
if (this.currentFrame == 1)
    {
        if (menuTextContinue_active.visible != false)
        {
            menuTextContinue_active.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuTextNewgame_active.visible != false)
        {
            menuTextNewgame_active.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuTextOptions_active.visible != false)
        {
            menuTextOptions_active.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuTextExitgame_active.visible != false)
        {
            menuTextExitgame_active.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuButton_continue.visible != false)
        {
            menuButton_continue.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuButton_newgame.visible != false)
        {
            menuButton_newgame.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuButton_options.visible != false)
        {
            menuButton_options.visible = false;
        }
        if (menuButton_exitgame.visible != false)
        {
            menuButton_exitgame.visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Can all be replaced with this:

```
If (this.currentFrame == 1){
    if (uiElements.visible != false){
        uiElements.visible = false;
    }
}
```

if you simply put all those buttons and movie clips into one parent container called `uiElements`.

**edit 11-12-16**

first make sure you import `flash.display.*`

To create a container do this outside any function:

```
var uiElements:Sprite = new Sprite(); // this creates an instance of the Sprite class
```

(A Sprite is the same as a movie clip but it has no timeline of its own, so it takes less memory)

Then in your main constructor do:

```
addChild(uiElements); // this adds the Sprite to the stage
```

Then, wherever you create elements that you want to add to that container do:

```
uiElements.addChild(yourNewMcHere); //this adds your other movie clip to the container
```

Does that make sense?

So that's the programmatic way to do it. If you are creating your elements in the IDE, you can do this simply by creating an empty MovieClip and adding all the other movie lips to it (like select a MovieClip, ctrl+x to cut, double click the movie clip you want to use as the container, ctrl+v to paste, repeat for all movie clips you want to add to this container. This is the same thing as what I have shown you to do programmatically).

Comment: Oh, cool. Yeah, it won't solve my problem, but it sure will help keep the code more consistent. I changed that bit slightly anyway; there wasn't really any checks needed.

Comment: How do I create the movie clip and how do I add all of them into it? Sorry, I'm new to Flash... I wasn't taught arrays at college.

Comment: Yeah, that makes a bit more sense. Thanks!